# ValueTuple<(string loanID, decimal x, ...)> does not contain a definition for 'loanID' in c#

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

I am just passing a ValueTuple to a function. I want to process the Values within this ValueTuple.

Unfortunately, VS 2017 only allows me to access `credit.Item1`. No further Items. So far I had no issues with ValueTuples.

The error in the compiler is:

> ValueTuple<(string loanID, decimal y, ...)> does not contain a
>   definition for 'loanID'...

The code is

```
public void LogCredit(
    ValueTuple<(
        string loanID,
        decimal discount,
        decimal interestRate,
        decimal realReturn,
        decimal term,
        int alreadyPayedMonths)>
    credit)
{
    // not working!
    string loanID = credit.loanID;

    // this is the only thing i can do:
    string loanID = credit.Item1;

    // not working either!
    decimal realReturn = credit.Item2;
}
```

Meanwhile, when hovering over `credit` I can see it correctly:
[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine generic syntax with c#'s newer builtin tuple support. What happens if you remove the `ValueTuple<` and `>` bits?

Comment: I think you're ending up with a tuple with one anonymous member, the type of that member being the tuple with named elements you're defining.

Comment: You have a tuple with a tuple inside, you sure this is what you want? Try simply removing `ValueTuple<` and the `>`, see if that gives you what you want. ie. your method declaration should be `public void LogCredit((string loanID, ...) credit) { ... }`.

Comment: Or, you can use the correct path to the fields: `string loanID = credit.Item1.loanID;`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the Trick. Anyone wants to post as Answer? otherwise Ill write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter has only one single field `Item1` because it is not of type `ValueTuple<...>`, but of type `ValueTuple<ValueTuple<...>>`: The single type parameter of the outer [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) is another `ValueTuple`, where this inner [C# tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) now contains your `string`, `decimal` and `int` fields.
Therefore, in your code you have to write `string loanID = credit.Item1.loanID;` to access those fields.

In order to access your fields as expected, remove the enclosing `ValueTuple`, leaving just the `C# tuple` behind:

```cs
public void LogCredit((string loanID, decimal discount, decimal interestRate,
    decimal realReturn, decimal term, int alreadyPayedMonths) credit)
{
    string loanID = credit.loanID;

    decimal realReturn = credit.Item4;
}
```

To utilize named fields of `ValueTuple`, I prefer the usage of the `C# 7 Tuples`.

For the sake of completeness, here is a [general blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) and an [in-depth blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/11/01/dissecting-the-tuples-in-c-7/) about tuples in C# 7.